# Error while installing "payum/stripe:*@stable"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, stripe-payments, payum

I am trying to install Stripe on my symfony2 project by running

```
$ php composer.phar require "payum/stripe:*@stable"
```

however i got this error message:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - Conclusion: don't install payum/stripe 0.14.0
> - Conclusion: don't install payum/stripe 0.13.0
> - Conclusion: don't install payum/stripe 0.12.0
> - Conclusion: don't install payum/stripe 0.11.0
> - Installation request for payum/stripe *@stable -> satisfiable by payum/stripe[0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0].
> - Conclusion: remove payum/payum 0.9.3
> - payum/stripe 0.10.0 requires payum/core 0.10.* -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.10.0, 0.10.x-dev].
> - don't install payum/core 0.10.0|don't install payum/payum 0.9.3
> - don't install payum/core 0.10.x-dev|don't install payum/payum 0.9.3
> - Installation request for payum/payum == 0.9.3.0 -> satisfiable by payum/payum[0.9.3].
> ```
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

my composer.json file content is as following:

```
{
"name": "itjari/xraydata",
"description": "XrayData : A New Start In The battle Against CyberBullying!",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "apache/log4php": "2.3.*@stable",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "4.3.*@stable",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "1.5.0.*@dev",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "4.0.*",
    "ob/highcharts-bundle": "dev-master",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@dev",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "~1.8.0",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "2.0.x-dev",
    "jmhobbs/swiftmailer-transport-aws-ses": "dev-master",
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "dev-master",
    "thobbs/phpcassa": "dev-master",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
    "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
    "zeptech/annotations": "1.1.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.5.*@dev",
    "misd/guzzle-bundle": "~1.0",
    "jms/payment-paypal-bundle": "~1",
    "payum/jms-payment-bridge": "0.9.*@dev",
    "omnipay/paypal": "~2.0",
    "omnipay/stripe": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "~1.5",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "dev-master",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "dev-master",
    "payum/stripe": "*@stable"
    },
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*@stable",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "1.3.*@stable",
    "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
    "behat/common-contexts": "*",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.*",
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
    "tedivm/fetch": "0.5.*",
    "zeptech/annotations": "1.1.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.5.*@dev",
"liuggio/fastest": "dev-master",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "2.7.x-dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
"discard-changes": true
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
     "payum/stripe": "0.15.*@dev" 
in your composer json.

https://packagist.org/packages/payum/stripe

then use the command :

```
$ php composer.phar require "payum/stripe"
```

It should be fine i'm not familiar with the @stable but it must be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use this:

```
php composer.phar require payum/stripe
```

In addition to that You Should Check this page which will guide you how to install the latest and stable version:

http://payum.org/doc/0.14/Stripe/checkout

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it by editing composer.json and adding payum/stripe:*@stable to require portion then run:

```
$ composer update
```

sounds weird to me but it works, letting you know that during this update and asks me to remove some dependencies and acquire others.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `"payum/jms-payment-bridge": "0.9.*@dev"` in your require section which means that `payum/core` of 0.9.x version is installed. Then you try to require a `"payum/stripe": "*@stable"` which is 0.14.* now. It simply not possible to have 0.9 and 0.14 at the same time.

Solution: set the version explicitly like `"payum/stripe": "~0.14.0"` and run composer update only for these packages

```

php composer.phar update payum/core payum/payum-bundle payum/stripe payum/jms-payment-bridge
```

FYI: it is not that safe to run `php composer.phar update` since it updates whole vendors and something maybe broken because of that. When you do that you have to run tests or tests the whole site manually.